# Symfony Api Platform not showing the api page correctly

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony

I am working on an existing project that was created by someone in Vue.js and Symfony. Right now I am trying to integrate "the login" module but it is not working. Specifically, I cannot login. In the `Login.vue` file there is an API calling for login `/api/login`.

Here is current code:

```
async Login() {
      const data = { username: this.email, password: this.password };
      this.loading = true;
         const response = await fetch(
        "/api/login",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
      );

      
        console.log('333', response)
        let newtoken = response.token
        this.$store.dispatch("loginSuccess", response.token);
        await this.getMyProfile(newtoken);
        if (this.$route.query.r) {
          await this.$router.push({ path: this.$route.query.r });
          //window.location.href = this.$route.query.r;
        } else {
          
          await this.$router.push({ path: "/center" });
         // window.location.href = "/center";
        }
      },
```

But I think the API is not working. Should I set any `base_url` in any file? Here is my `.env` file. Where I am wrong?

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/dating_sugar_sta?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.25&charset=utf8"
```

Comment: `Api is not working`, mind explaining a bit more? Got any error or useful server logs?

Comment: i am confused about API ENDPOINT, should i add apiendpoint  like "htttp://abc.com/api/login" ?